# WP 3.1 - archive pages for custom content types possible now without a plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, customization

I noticed that WP 3.1 supposedly has '[new CMS capabilities like archive pages for custom content types](http://wordpress.org/news/2011/02/threeone/)', however, I can't see that implemented yet?

I've been using a plugin called 'Simple Custom Post Type Archives' to view custom posts at the url http://www.domainname.com/custom-post-type/, but wanted to use the in-built capability considering it is 'now possible'.

Has anyone else had the same issue?

Thanks

osu

PS. I'm using archive-custom_post_type_name.php to try and style my custom post type archive page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you'll just need to set the `has_archive` parameter to true or your chosen slug when registering your custom post type.

So firstly add the `has_archive` parameter to your post type, here's an example...

```
add_action( 'init', 'question_10706_init' );

function question_10706_init() {

    register_post_type( 'example', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Examples'),
            'singular_name' => __('Example')
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'example',
            'with_front' => false
            ),
        //'has_archive' => true // Will use the post type slug, ie. example
        //'has_archive' => 'my-example-archive' // Explicitly setting the archive slug
    ) );

}
```

The `has_archive` parameter supports the following settings.

1. **false** (default)

   *No archive*
2. **true**

   *The archive url is formulated from the post type slug*

   `www.example.com/example/`
3. '**string**'

   *The archive url is explicitly set to the slug you provided*

   `www.example.com/my-example-archive/`

Once you've added the parameter visit the permalink page, this will cause a regeneration of the rewrite rules, accounting for the custom post type archive.

Lastly, create an `archive-{$post_type}.php` template to handle that archive (it could be a straight copy->paste of your existing archive, make adjustments as necessary).
Noting, that `{$post_type}` would of course represent the slug of your actual post type.

**Sourced information:**

- Mark McWilliams also wrote about this
  on his blog:
  **[WordPress 3.1 Introduces Custom Post Type Archives](http://mark.mcwilliams.me/2010/10/wordpress-3-1-introduces-custom-post-type-archives/)**
- Trac ticket that introduced the new
  post type archives.
  **[Ticket #13818 - There should be index pages for custom post
  types](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13818)**

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Absolutely superb. Thanks so much, worked perfectly!

Comment: It would be useful if there was a nice way to create a menu item to this as well; I have to use an external link, the menu for which then doesn't get the appropriate classes when the menu item is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is implemented in 3.1, you have to make sure that the arguments passed to `register_post_type` have the `has_archive` flag set to true. See the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) about it.

You might also need to visit your permalink settings page and resubmit them, that seems to help things often.