# Can anyone clarify difference between archive-{posttype}.php, type-{posttype} and date.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, date-time

I'm trying to get the custom archives per post-type working, but after a week of trying, searching and scratching head I still cannot get it working. I'm mainly talking about the `{post-type}/{year}` or `{post-type}/{year}/{month}` permalinks. They always throw a `404`. Only `index.php?year={year}&monthnum={month}&post_type={post_type}` links do work. So right now I temporarily created some custom rewrite rules which translate permalinks in working links.

But, how to get the native archive functionality working for post-types? I am clueless about what is the difference between the `archive-{posttype}.php`, `type-{posttype}` and `date.php` templates and tried all of them to get them working. No luck though. `type-{posttype}.php` does work in order to list all the post-types, but `archive-{posttype}.php` or `date.php` do not make the `/{year}/{month}` permalinks to work.

Basically what I need is:

`/{post-type}` to list all the posts of this custom post type

`/{post-type}/{year}` to list all of them of a particular year

`/{post-type}/{year}/{month}` to specify further on a month.

And lastly: is there a template to be created which outputs all the years and months of the custom post type with `wp_get_archives()`? Or do I have to create a different template to create them for each post-type?

Hope I was a bit clear. Running on wp3.1

Answer (score 1):

What do your permalink structure look like? Have you already read [this on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)?

EDIT: similar thread [over here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/wp-3-1-archive-pages-for-custom-content-types-possible-now-without-a-plugin). Might fit your needs.

Comment: tnx, it's a start! /{post-type} archive pages work now, but /{post-type}/{year}/{month} pages still throw 404's.

Comment: @Mixhael: Normally it should be `http://example.com/{year}/{month}/{day}/{sample-post}/` according to the permalinks settings (admin ui > settings > permalinks > 2nd choice "day and name"). Are you sure about what you're trying to acchieve?

Comment: ok, so this means that post-type specific date based archives only work with custom rewrite rules?

Comment: Until 3.1 custom post types had no archives at all. I haven't got enough time to take a deeper look into it now, but i guess there should already be some documentation about it at the codex. From a short google i only found this link. Maybe it helps: http://mark.mcwilliams.me/2010/10/wordpress-3-1-introduces-custom-post-type-archives/

Answer (score 1):

You should consider asking one question at a time.

> And lastly: is there a template to be
>   created which outputs all the years
>   and months of the custom post type
>   with wp_get_archives()? Or do I have
>   to create a different template to
>   create them for each post-type?

You mean like this: http://scribu.net/wordpress/smart-archives-reloaded

Comment: You're right. Not so sure if this is what I mean, will look into it. Tnx